# Dropping duplicate values in a column only in specific ranges of row indices in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a test dataframe `df` from which I want to drop duplicate values in the `Hits` column but not the rows associated with the duplicate values. The condition however is that the dropping is to be done only in some specific ranges of row indices.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Hits = c("#a", "#ID:987129470", "#b", "Hit1", "Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit3", "Hit3", "#a", "#ID:6971324987", "#b", "Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit2", "Hit3"),
  Category1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, NA, NA, NA, 0.023, 0.341, 0.341, 0.569),
  Category2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, NA, NA, NA, 100, 95, 95, 97),
  Category3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, NA, NA, NA, 98, 97, 97, 92))
```

`df` looks like this

[image]

The ranges of row indices in which the dropping operation is to be carried out are `4:8` and `12:15` in this case. Basically, the duplicate hits under each ID are to be dropped, keeping the associated values in the other columns intact. The output should look something like this

[image]

In the original dataframe (which has ~100k rows!) it is not possible to specify the ranges. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make groups by starting with `#a`
then use an `ifelse` statement.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id_Group = cumsum(Hits=="#a")) %>% 
  mutate(Hits = ifelse(duplicated(Hits), "", Hits)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-id_Group)
```

```
  Hits             Category1 Category2 Category3
   <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 "#a"                NA            NA        NA
 2 "#ID:987129470"     NA            NA        NA
 3 "#b"                NA            NA        NA
 4 "Hit1"               0.001       100       100
 5 ""                   0.001       100       100
 6 "Hit2"               0.002        99        99
 7 "Hit3"               0.003        98        98
 8 ""                   0.003        98        98
 9 "#a"                NA            NA        NA
10 "#ID:6971324987"    NA            NA        NA
11 "#b"                NA            NA        NA
12 "Hit1"               0.023       100        98
13 "Hit2"               0.341        95        97
14 ""                   0.341        95        97
15 "Hit3"               0.569        97        92
```

Comment: Perfect! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Hits = c("#a", "#ID:987129470", "#b", "Hit1", "Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit3", "Hit3", "#a", "#ID:6971324987", "#b", "Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit2", "Hit3"),
  Category1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, NA, NA, NA, 0.023, 0.341, 0.341, 0.569),
  Category2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, NA, NA, NA, 100, 95, 95, 97),
  Category3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, NA, NA, NA, 98, 97, 97, 92))

df %>% 
  group_by(Hits, if_else(str_detect(Hits, "Hits*"), 1, 0) %>% data.table::rleid(.)) %>% 
  mutate(Hits = if_else(row_number() > 1 & str_detect(Hits, "Hits*"), "", Hits)) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-last_col())

#> # A tibble: 15 × 4
#>    Hits             Category1 Category2 Category3
#>    <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 "#a"                NA            NA        NA
#>  2 "#ID:987129470"     NA            NA        NA
#>  3 "#b"                NA            NA        NA
#>  4 "Hit1"               0.001       100       100
#>  5 ""                   0.001       100       100
#>  6 "Hit2"               0.002        99        99
#>  7 "Hit3"               0.003        98        98
#>  8 ""                   0.003        98        98
#>  9 "#a"                NA            NA        NA
#> 10 "#ID:6971324987"    NA            NA        NA
#> 11 "#b"                NA            NA        NA
#> 12 "Hit1"               0.023       100        98
#> 13 "Hit2"               0.341        95        97
#> 14 ""                   0.341        95        97
#> 15 "Hit3"               0.569        97        92
```